# Controlling Office 2007 with .NET: which direction?

Tags: .net, com, interop, sourcegear-fortress

I want to retrieve items from [Fortress](http://www.sourcegear.com/fortress) via its .NET API and load their descriptions into Project 2007. I was thinking about the 'best' way to do this, so I thought I would put it to my fellow stackers:

Should I write a .NET assembly and wrap it in COM for Project 2007 to call from VBA?

Or should I write a .NET assembly that calls Project 2007 via COM?

Which is better from a performance perspective? What would **you** do?

Comment: Is the goal to simply open them?  or are you using programmatic modification of the documents?

Comment: I updated the question to point out the specifics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would lean towards a solution using a .NET assembly, however, this really depends on your needs.  If you are simply pulling the file, loading it and that is all I would go the .NET Assembly route, as you can simply use Process.Start() to show it to the user.

If you are making heavy modifications though, you might gain SOME performance benefits by doing the modifications via VBA and going the route of a .NET assembly that is wrapped in COM to actually obtain the file(s).

This relly depends on the end solution that you are looking for.